# AS400 Level check on DSPF

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I made a change to a display file using Screen Design Aid, saved the DDS source file and compiled the object. 
I then checked the Format Level Identifier of that File using DSPFD.

The RPGLE program that compliments this Screen was no change. 
I first checked the Format Level Identifier for the file on this program using DSPPGMREF and it was different. So I recompiled the RPGLE and the Format Level Identifiers still don't match no matter how much times I recompile.

And well obviously If i try to call the RPG program I get a level check error. 
CPF4131

Additionally, 
The RPGLE program is a copy of another program I am trying to edit and test without disrupting the original version. So I have two RPG programs in the same library calling the file. The copy program is suffixed with CPY at the end. 
I'm not sure if this would also have anything to do with it.

I checked WRKOBJ and there is only one object of the copy program. And my Library lists are in the correct order.

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: wrkobj *all/mydisplayfile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some likely causes for this but they all amount to basically the same problem.  You are not accessing the object you think you are when compiling.  I suggest checking the following:

1. You don't have your library list set up correctly to include the
   library the DDS object is in.
2. You have your library list set up such that it is picking up the
   old DDS object before it finds the new one.
3. You are compiling the DDS object to a different library than you
   expect.

Also try running `WRKOBJ *ALL/<OBJNAME>`.  You might be surprised to find a version hanging out somewhere you didn't expect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unforunately, I did check all these things and everything is in order, WRKOBJ just shows the one object which is the one I am trying to call and my library lists are good. I edited the question to add more information if it helps

Comment: Have you tried running DSPPGM to see that the build date and time is getting updated as expected?

Comment: DSPPGM shows a creation date of 2 weeks ago. Which is correct for when it was created but does this date update with each compile ??

Comment: Yes.  This should be updated every time the object gets recompiled.

Comment: In case you haven't tried it yet, I would delete the program object and recompile just to see if it recreates it then.

Comment: I've had that occur when there is an ownership problem with the object.  It will appear to compile successfully but not replace the object.  Follow Player1sts suggestion and delete (or rename might be better) the object first.

Comment: Just wanted to check that when recompiling the RPGLE you did create a /program/ and not just a /module/?

Comment: Deleting and recompiling was a good option I had not even thought about. Thanks Player1st

Comment: Glad I could help.  Thanks for the check.